# QTcpSocket connection

Tags: qt

I'm trying to write a chat using QTcpSocket and QTcpServer.
Several pieces of my code

Client

```
ChatClient::ChatClient(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent) {
    connect(&tcpSocket, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)),
            this, SLOT(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));
    connect(&tcpSocket, SIGNAL(connected()),
            this, SLOT(requestForID()));
    connect(&tcpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),
            this, SLOT(receiveMessage()));
    tcpSocket.connectToHost(QHostAddress::LocalHost, PORT);
}

void ChatClient::requestForID() {
    qDebug() << "Connected, requesting for ID";
    QByteArray segment;
    QDataStream out(segment);
    out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_7);
    out << (quint16)0 << ID;
    out.device()->seek(0);
    out << (quint16)(segment.size() - sizeof(quint16));
    tcpSocket.write(segment);
}

void ChatClient::error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError error) {
    qDebug() << "Socket error" << error;
}
```

Server

```
ChatServer::ChatServer(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent) {
    if (!tcpServer.listen(QHostAddress::LocalHost, PORT)) {
        qDebug() << "Unable to start the server"
                 << tcpServer.errorString();
    }
    connect(&tcpServer, SIGNAL(newConnection()),
            this, SLOT(processConnection()));
}
```

Client socket never gets connected. Error is never being printed.
PORT = 6178.
Runnig KUbuntu. Ping to localhost from bash is successful.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: both tcpserver and tcpClient seem to be non pointer member variables and you don't seem to have initialized them.

Comment: That's an idea. I'll try and reply what results.

Comment: Converted both to pointers and initialized with new QTcp*(this), but still doesn't work =(

Comment: @Abhijith - that doesn't matter at all... They will initialize with ChatClient/Server class initialization, with default constructors: QTcpSocket(QObject * parent = NULL) and QTcpServer(QObject * parent = NULL).

Comment: @OneMoreVladimir Can you give more code for client/server? Maybe problem is laying somwhere else in your code.

Comment: Yes. Sometimes I'm surprised with how stupid I am. In main function I didn't create ChatServer object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any errors in your code, are you sure your Qt and "network" is working properly? Qt should emit an error but at least your code pieces here look correct to me. Maybe your code never gets called, add some debug messages to the methods.

At last you can build the Qt Network examples and test if that is working on your machine. If you don't have the examples take a look here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-network.html (Fortune Server/Client for TCP)

Comment: Thanks for you reply Xander. I've built tripplanner and tripserver examples (from Programming Qt GUI 4) and they do work, the only difference is that tripserver is using QTcpSocket instead of QTcpServer. According to the http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/network-fortuneserver.html I do not see any errors too.